# Wrong sign with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm using `Mathematica` to integrate this function:

```
w[x_, z_] := 
 E^x/(E^x + 1)^2 Log[(E^(z^2/(4 x)) + E^-x)/(E^(z^2/(4 x)) - 1)]
W[z_] := NIntegrate[w[x, z], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

where `z > 0` is a positive parameter. Analytically, I know that the integrated is non-negative, so the integral itself should be non-negative. However, I'm getting some incorrect results due to a lack of accuracy:

```
W[100]
```

[image]
[image]

```
-6.05023*10^-20
```

**My question:** How can I get a reliable result? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
w[x_, z_] := E^x/(E^x + 1)^2 Log[(E^(z^2/(4 x)) + E^-x)/(E^(z^2/(4 x)) - 1)]
```

For larger `z` the integrand is very small and high precision is required in the integration.

```
Plot3D[w[x, z], {x, 0, 40}, {z, 0, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
W2[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[w[x, z], {x, 0, ∞},
  WorkingPrecision -> 40,
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

W2[100]

(* 4.679853458969239635780655689865016458810*10^-43 *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying and rearranging the integrand, along with high precision, solves the problem in this case:

```
With[{z = 100}, 
     NIntegrate[1/4 Sech[x/2]^2 Log[(1 + E^-x E^(-(z^2/(4 x))))/(1 - E^(-(z^2/(4 x))))],
                {x, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]]
   4.679853735636909286562544*10^-43
```

In particular, the important part here was to try to express the integrand in terms of functions that decay at infinity, like $\exp(-x)$ or $\operatorname{sech} x$.

Comment: Point taken, thanks a lot.